# JAX-WS wsimport with multiple wsdl files

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservice-client

I'm attempting to write a number of web service clients. I have been presented with a number of wsdl's, all of which make references to a number of common data structures.

I'm wanting to use wsimport to allow me to produce a web service client jar file. The command I'm running is along the lines of

```
wsimport src/*wsdl -d target
```

First of all, does this seem a reasonable thing to do?

If I run `wsimport src/srv1.wsdl -d target` I get what appears to be a reasonable set of java classes produced. Similary, if I run `wsimport src/srv2.wsdl -d target` I also get a reasonable set of classes.

However, if I run `wsimport -d targey src/srv1.wsdl src/srv2.wsdl` I get a large number of classes produced, but the Service class the srv2 in not created. The package where I would expect to find it is there, but it is empty.

I'm using the basic wsimport that comes as part of JDK6

Am I doing something wrong here?

Dave

Answer (score 2):

I am using wsimport in my current project to import a wsdl file for a wcf webservice.
I do not know if you can specify multiple wsdl files to import in a single wsimport statement but, you can individually process each wsdl file using something like :

```
wsimport -d <directory-for-generated-classes> <wsdl-file-location>
```

Here the -d is used to specify the directory in which you want to place the compiled classes (replace  with the path to the directory in which you want to place the compiled classes. If you do not specify a directory then the compiled classes are placed in the current working directory)

If you want to generate the source java files too, then you can use something like :

```
wsimport -d <directory-for-generated-classes> -s <directory-for-generated-source> <wsdl-file-location>
```

-s is used to specify the directory in which you want to place the generated source java files.

If you want to generate a jar file consisting of all the compiled class files for a particular wsdl file then you can use something like :

```
wsimport -d <directory-for-jar-file> -clientjar jarfilename.jar <wsdl-file-location>
```

This places the jar file in the specified directory but does not keep the generated the compiled class files. All the class files are packaged in the jar.

You can view additional options by issuing the command :

```
wsimport -help
```

Regarding, processing multiple wsdl files, you can maybe create a batch file that processes multiple wsdl files specified using a single wsimport statement in each line.

Hope it helps :)